# Angular 6: Build Quiz using FormGroup and save data through Pagination

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, pagination, formgroups

**EDIT** 
[this is my full project in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wc6zeu?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts)
course-quiz is in course-play folder (course-play is parent of course-quiz)

I'm trying to build a quiz which separate to pages (each page have one question). I'm using Pagination to do this. 
The data pass from backend and there's no problems with html and http requests.
I don't need to save the answers to a database, so I want to use a local array somehow.

This is how the quiz looks like: [image]

If I check answer and move to another page and return the that page the data's gone.
I don't know which data structure to use (maybe array of int?) and because the submit button only on the last page I don't know when to do the update (when I set the pager?). How do I save the data using formGroup?
This is my code so far:

**component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { ICourse } from '../../course';
import { ISegment } from '../../course';
import { IQuestion } from '../../course';
import { CourseService } from '../../course.service';
import { PagerService } from '../../pager.service';

import * as _ from 'underscore';

@Component({
  selector: 'quiz-course',
  templateUrl: './course-quiz.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-quiz.component.sass']
})

export class CourseQuizComponent implements OnInit {

  // the data I get from course-play component
  @Input() items: IQuestion[];

  // variables for pagination
  pagedItems: IQuestion[];
  pager: any = {};

  answersArray: any[];              // array of answers the user choose
  index: int;                      // current index of answersArray
  sum: int;                       // number of answers the user answered
  public quizForm: FormGroup     // radio buttons in the quiz form

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router,
      private fb: FormBuilder,
      private pagerService: PagerService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setPage(1);
    this.index = 0;
    this.sum = 0;
    this.checked = false;

    this.quizForm = this.fb.group({
      selected: [{value: ''}, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  // change pages
  setPage(page: number) {
    if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
        return;
    }

    // get pager object from service
    this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.items.length, page);

    // get current page of items
    this.pagedItems = this.items.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);

    // do something here to update answersArray
  }

  // getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() {
    return this.quizForm.controls;
  }

  // insert to local array the answers of the user after he press submit
  onSubmit() {

  // if we answered all answers, go to finish page
  if (this.sum == this.items.length) { }


  }

}
```

**html**

```html
<!-- If the user didn't answer all the questions -->
  <div class="container" *ngIf="sum < pager.totalPages">
      <div class="text-left quiz-body" *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">
        <form [formGroup]="quizForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <!-- items being paged -->
          <h3>Question {{item.id}}/{{items.length}}</h3>
          <h6>Question {{item.question}}</h6>
          <div class="form-group">
            <mat-radio-group FormControlName="selected" class="form-control">
              <ul class="items">
                <li><mat-radio-button color="primary" id="answer1" value="1"></mat-radio-button><label for="answer1">1. {{item.answer1}}</label></li>
                <li><mat-radio-button color="primary" id="answer2" value="2"></mat-radio-button><label for="answer2">2. {{item.answer2}}</label></li>
                <li><mat-radio-button color="primary" id="answer3" value="3"></mat-radio-button><label for="answer3">3. {{item.answer3}}</label></li>
                <li><mat-radio-button color="primary" id="answer4" value="4"></mat-radio-button><label for="answer4">4. {{item.answer4}}</label></li>
              </ul>
            </mat-radio-group>
          </div>

          <!-- Submit Buttom will show only on the last page -->
          <div *ngIf="pager.currentPage == pager.totalPages">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
          </div>


          <!-- pager -->
          <ul *ngIf="pager.pages && pager.pages.length" class="pagination">
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === 1}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let page of pager.pages" [ngClass]="{active:pager.currentPage === page}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(pager.currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
              </li>
              <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled:pager.currentPage === pager.totalPages}">
                  <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(pager.totalPages)">Last</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>


<!-- If the user finished the quiz, this div will displaying instead -->
<div class="container" *ngIf="sum == pager.totalPages">
  <h3> You have just finished the quiz! </h3>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

this is the pagination service:

```js
import * as _ from 'underscore';

export class PagerService {
    getPager(totalItems: number, currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number = 1) {
        // calculate total pages
        let totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        let startPage: number, endPage: number;
        // if (totalPages <= 10) {
        //     // less than 10 total pages so show all
        //     startPage = 1;
        //     endPage = totalPages;
        // } else {
        //     // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
        //     if (currentPage <= 6) {
        //         startPage = 1;
        //         endPage = 10;
        //     } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
        //         startPage = totalPages - 9;
        //         endPage = totalPages;
        //     } else {
        //         startPage = currentPage - 5;
        //         endPage = currentPage + 4;
        //     }
        // }

        if (totalPages <= 5) {
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            if (currentPage <= 3) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 5;
            } else if (currentPage + 1 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 4;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 2;
                endPage = currentPage+2;
            }
        }

        // calculate start and end item indexes
        let startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        let pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are loading the question and it's possible answers each time you click on the page numbers. Even if the page has been loaded earlier, you are loading it again. This will create 2 problems 1) Overhead of HTTP calls and 2) Removing previously selected answers. You need to somehow check if the page has already been loaded earlier. If it has then you don't load it again. This way you will preserve your answers too.

Comment: So basically everytime you call the setPage method, you update an array called loadedPageNumbers. So say you clicked on page 4, you now check in the array if page 4 exists in loadedPageNumbers, then you don't do the service call again

Comment: how do I do that? and isn't it initialize it every-time it's load a new page? I think maybe if I can implement pagination differently it'll be possible, but how can I implement pagination in a way that'll now load the page every-time?

Comment: Service is not for multi components, its for handling data logic or anything that SERVE you in any way. HTTP requests, mockup api, static data that need to be managed, Spinners, Navigations. You can use it as you need. and in your case, you need to manage some kind of state between questions. So you can create a service that provided only in this specific module and live as long as you are using the quiz module.

Comment: I have service for the pagination, so maybe I need to update it? if so I don't know how because it's a code I copied. I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, i would instead route the whole question module and use a sharign service to handle that.

I made a quick [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kpgkld?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion%2Fquestion.component.ts) to show you an example.

of course, it can be improved, but it's only to give you an idea on what I would do.

I think that your case is the perfect example of routing. And not only that, but your code will become more readable, reusable, and clear with this approach.

Comment: what's the purpose of the service? service is good when working with multiple components but I have only one. do you mean add another component of question?

Comment: also, I get from a backend array IQuestion[] that contains this fields: question: string, answer1: string, answer2: string, answer3: string, answer4: string, correct: int. in any quiz there's only 4 answers and correct contains the number of the correct answer (1,2,3,4).

Comment: In my case, there is two components (I just edited the blitz). And even if there was only one, a service is a singleton : it will hold the data until the application is destroyed (refresh, browser closed ...). According to the style guide, services should also handle business code, and questions are your business. And as said, I made a quick example, but nothing prevents you from requesting your questions from the backend and changing the data model.

Comment: this is a small part in my project, In fact I have Courses and every course contains segments which is or video or quiz. I don't understand how service will solve my problem with the pagination. someone wrote that the pagination load new pages every time I change the page and I can't save data, and also I have a difficulty understanding how the flow with the service. If you could explain a little further I'd be great, and thanks for the help

Comment: The service is useful for storing the data. As you can see, my service saves the data and doesn't have an issue with pagination. I have commented the blitz with steps to follow. Start at `app.module.ts`

Comment: Actually my comment supposed to be here and not directly in your question, But I will leave it there... Your service should do exactly what you asked for. Save your states between questions, so when you go back you can pull it from the service and fetch it in your view.

Comment: and if you have a service for the pagination, just update the current state of you question. so you have like QUIZ object, which holds all the answers, so you can pull it back when ever you need.

Comment: I have a little problem with using it because this component is a child to other component and get the data with Input Injectable so if I use service I don't know how I can inject that data to the service. service can use Input Injectable too? and what do you mean by state of the question? add property in the pager service for this?

Comment: I added my full project in stackblitz and added link in the question so my problem will be clear

Answer (score -1):

1. If you can identify questions by index then array will be fine. The other question is that it might be not array of integers but array of objects for case when user should select more than one answer for single question (not radio, but checkbox)
2. You have to process not only submit but navigation to other pages and store selected answer(s) in the array when user navigate to other page

**EDIT**

You can implement saving of selected answer by subscribing on radio group chnage value event:

```
this.formGroup.controls['selected'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    // TODO: save selected abswer in the array
});
```

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: there's always one option only to check. we get object that only contain the questions info. I don't need to save to a database the answers, only locally to know if he answer correct or finished. each question contain the question, 4 answers and correct which contain the number of the correct answer (1 || 2 || 3|| 4||). I want that when the user check answer that the data will save automatically and bind to array or something (I'll save the data in index that fits the page number). I don't how to implement this so this is my problem

Comment: I have add code example you can use to subscribe on radio group change value event